# Defunct processes, fork()

Tags: c, fork

If I run this program will I have defunct processes? I am trying to create a main program that runs 5 process in parallell and then not getting defunct processes. The trouble is mostly to be sure that this is not happening. Im not quite sure if Im doing it right this far. I have heard that it is good practice to make sure you dont have defunct processes by making your process "wait()" for as many children that has been "fork()"ed.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void forkChildren(int nrofChildren, int *nr_of_children) {
    pid_t pid;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
        /* fork a child process */
        pid = fork();
        (*nr_of_children)++;
        /* error occurred */
        if (pid < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
        /* successful child */
        else if (pid == 0) {
            int sleeptime=1; //rand()%10;
            printf("I am child: %d \nwith parent: %d \nin loop: %d \nand will sleep for: %d sec\n\n", getpid(), getppid(), i, sleeptime);
            sleep(sleeptime);
            printf("Ending of child: %d \nwith parent :%d in loop: %d\n\n", getpid(), getppid(), i);
        }
        /* parent process 
        else {
            wait(NULL); Do I need this to make sure I dont get defunct processes???
        } */
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    int nr_of_children=0;
    if (argc < 2) {
        /* if no argument run 5 childprocesses */
        forkChildren(5, &nr_of_children);
    } else {
        forkChildren(atoi (argv[1]), &nr_of_children);
    }
    wait(NULL);
    printf("End of %d, with %d nr of child-processes\n\n", getpid(), nr_of_children);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *all* process become defunct after the terminate.  If you `wait` for them, they will be zombies for a very short time.  If you exit or return from main, they will be zombies for a very short time because they will be adopted by init who will wait for them.

Comment: Why don't you use the returnvalue for passing the number of produces children back to the caller, instead of the void() function with the silly `*nr_of_children` pointer to the result?

Comment: @wildplasser Aha that was an idea, I did not think about, thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to `wait` on the child processes. The reason is that otherwise there will still be data associated with the now zombie process, for example space for the process return value.

Comment: So do you mean I will have to have the wait(NULL) in the else statement for making sure of it?

Comment: @patriques Yes, otherwise you will have "zombie" processes lingering around in the system.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at using the daemon() command to place your app in the background, then use pthreads to manage the parallelism.

> **NAME**
>          daemon - run in the background
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>          #include
>
> ```
>    int daemon(int nochdir, int noclose);
> ```
>
> Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see
>   feature_test_macros(7)):
>
> ```
>    daemon(): _BSD_SOURCE || (_XOPEN_SOURCE && _XOPEN_SOURCE < 500)
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>          The daemon() function is for programs wishing to detach themselves from the controlling terminal and run in the background as
>   system daemons.
>
> ```
>    If nochdir is zero, daemon() changes the process’s current working directory to the root directory ("/"); otherwise,
>
>    If noclose is zero, daemon() redirects standard input, standard output and standard error to /dev/null; otherwise, no changes are made
> ```
>
> to these file descriptors.